# Ionic View One Fixed, One Scrolling Section

Tags: ionic-framework

OK so I have the following code:

```html
<ion-view hide-back-button="true", title="Test">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-slide-box>
      <ion-slide>
        <img style="width: 100%" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/2001_BMW_Z3_Sideview_Topdown_Topaz_Blue_2.5i.jpg">
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <img style="width: 100%" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/BMW_Z3_1.9L_1998.jpg">
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <img style="width: 100%" src="http://www.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/bmw-z3-black.jpg">
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
    <div class="bar bar-dark">
      <h1 class="title">Feed</h1>
    </div>
    <ion-list style="padding: 1px;">
      <ion-item ng-repeat="test in tests" href="#/detail/{{work.id}}">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2>{{test.name}}</h2>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I want the list to scroll independently of the rest of the view and for the bar and nothing above it to scroll -- ie I want them to be fixed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix, just use two ion-scrolls: see it here: http://play.ionic.io/app/85e2270b0b33

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
      <ion-view hide-back-button="true", title="Test">
  <ion-scroll>
    <ion-slide-box>
      <ion-slide>
        <img style="width: 100%" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/2001_BMW_Z3_Sideview_Topdown_Topaz_Blue_2.5i.jpg">
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <img style="width: 100%" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/BMW_Z3_1.9L_1998.jpg">
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <img style="width: 100%" src="http://www.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/bmw-z3-black.jpg">
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
    <div class="bar bar-dark">
      <h1 class="title">Feed</h1>
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
    <ion-scroll style="height: 500px">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          Hello
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          Hello
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          Hello
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          Hello
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          Hello
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          Hello
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          Hello
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          Hello
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          Hello
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          Hello
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-scroll>
  </ion-view>
  </body>
</html>
```